# How to handle nested Git repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to share my vim configuaration with git. but some vim plugin is install from git repository

directory like this

```
configs/.git/
configs/vim/
configs/vim/bundle/xxxx/
configs/vim/bundle/xxxx/.git/
configs/vim/bundle/yyyy/
configs/vim/bundle/yyyy/.git/
```

I want my repository smallest, so I don't want to add xxxx/.git  yyyy/.git in my git, if I doesnt add them, a clean fetch will not contains xxxx/.git, so I could not update xxxx and yyyy.

how can I do it well, BTW, can I update config,xxxx,yyyy in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use submodules like so:

[Git Community Book: Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

You'll then be able to update all the submodules at once using:

```
git submodule update
```